# How to show a link above the wordpress BlogRoll (left column) only o the home page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking to figure out how could I show a link on the left menu of my website that would appear only when We are on the Home page.

It should looks like this, but only for the home page (look at the link called Recommended VoIP Service ) : http://abvoip.com/

Is that possible to do so directly in the admin panel ? otherwise, which file do I have to modify ? Cause I'm working in the default-widgets.php file, in the widget function, but I know it is not the way it is supposed to be ...

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to put this code in your sidebar.php template. Do you have a sidebar.php file in your theme? If so could you post the contents of that file to your initial question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very easily by using a conditional tag. Conditional tags, like the `is_home()` function, test to see whether the provided conditions are true or not. In this case, we are testing whether or not we are on the home page. If you place this within an if statement, the code inside that statement will only be executed if `is_home()` is true.

Take the following code for adding the "Recommended VoIP Service" to the sidebar:

```
<?php 
    if ( is_home() ) {
        echo '<div style="font-size:16px; font:black; margin-bottom:20px;"><a href="http://www.axvoice.com">Recommended VoIP Service</a></div>';  
    }
?>
```

This will effectively only display the "Recommended VoIP Service" list item when you are in fact on the home page.

You can find more information on wordpress conditional tags here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Thanks dpcasady, I don't really know where to put that code, because, as I said in my question, I'm pretty sure i'm dealing with the wrong file, and I have no idea about which files should contain personnal modification. I'm very new to Wp thus, but I know php

Comment: Oh, one last thing, I was talking about the menu on the left side, where you can see the "Recommended VoIP Service" that should be shown only on the home page

Comment: oh okay, sorry about that, let me edit my response to reflect that. Are you putting the div holding the "Recommended VoIP Service" into the default_widgets.php file directly or into a widget?

Comment: thanks for your EDIT,
in which file should I put that code ? in my default-widget.php file, in the WP_Widget_Text, I've added your code (that works, thanks !) in the widget function, but I'm not sure that the best fit for that code.

Comment: No problem, yes you're correct, you should not be putting code into the default_widget.php file. I'll add another revision to my answer to help you out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10067/discussion-between-dpcasady-and-miles-m)